# jQuery on DOM element found at any time

Tags: jquery

In jQuery I want to say at any time this DOM element shows up do this. So kinda like .live() or .on() at any time the DOM element is found, hide it.

Comment: hmmm.... I would suggest using plain old css for this.

Comment: Can't use CSS, because it's dynamic. Based on true or false, if this DOM element EVER shows up. Hide it.

Comment: Then you will have to use whatever is adding it to the dom to run the code that hides it. Otherwise you will need to find a plugin that detects when elements are added the the dom. jQuery core does not have a method for that.

Comment: I wish this question were worded more generally because as it is, the answers given using CSS are correct, but what if you wanted to do something more interesting, like transform the element into a different kind of element (as with jQuery UI controls) then CSS isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

Say you wanted to achieve this...

```
if (myCondition) {
    $(".myClass").hide();
}
```

But you don't know when the `myClass` item will show up, you could do the following:

CSS:

```
.shouldHide .myClass {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
if (myCondition) {
    $("body").addClass("shouldHide");
}
```

This means you can still apply the condition by adding / removing the `shouldHide` class on the body tag, and you have a CSS rule that will hide `myClass` if the body tag has the `shouldHide` class.

Comment: I don't think this works, because when you run your conditional check the element might not be on the page yet.

Comment: @Mark - that shouldn't matter - unless the condition is related specifically to the element - because you flag the page to say whether the content should be hidden. If you let me know the specific rules I can adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, just use CSS. Even if the element is generated after the page is created the CSS will be applied. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/YB2bk/. In this example, a page has one div that when clicked, creates a new div. Both divs get the same CSS applied.